# why fixed didn't work when root node have something styles?

Tags: html, css

[demo address](http://jsfiddle.net/qctLzas1/3/)

```css
.father {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}

.child {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="father">
  <div class="child">

  </div>
</div>
```

The "child" node position is fixed,but it cut out by the "father" node,
if I adjust the style of the 'father' node,it can be display normal.for example,I remove 'z-index:999;' or 'border-radius:6px;' or 'overflow:hidden;' or 'position:absolute;',every one above I remove,the 'child' node can be display ok ,who can explain it?Some suggestions would be great.

Comment: OK,I have add the demo address on the top of the article,please help me check it,what's wrong~

Comment: this seems to be a bug in Chrome, try using Fiferox and it will render fine

Comment: @Temani Afif Have you try in firefox it's working properly.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one if you want the **father div** should be on the **child div** so no need to give **z-index: 999;** to father div you have to give **z-index: -1;** to the child div.

```css
.father {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  left:50px;
  top:50px;
}

.child{
  position: fixed;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="father">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And the thing that's confusing to me is, why set 'father' node 'z-index',the 'child' node postion fixed didn't work.